# VBA Word: Property Revision.Style dosn't work

Tags: vba, ms-word

When I try to change some styles (e.g. textcolor) in a revisions object I get a `Run-Time error '5852'` (requested object is not available). I've used `ActiveDocument.Revisions(i).Style` ... Other properties are available (author, creator, type, ...). Btw: I really want change the style from the revision (not the ordinary text). Tested in Word 2010 & 2016

edit: a bit more detailed:

I try to change the color of the revisions that is displayed. Word sets it automically by default. But you can't choose which color Word assigns to reviewers ([See this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/advanced-track-changes-options-in-word-2016-for-mac-42ff9070-0aca-4ced-9755-7fbd69b72859?omkt=en-001&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US))

Unfortunately this is exactly what I want to do. So I tried it with VBA and actually there is the property style available for the [revision object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/revision-object-word), but I get an `error 5852` in line with `ActiveDocument.Revisions(i).Style`

```
Sub test()
    i = 1
    While i <= ActiveDocument.Revisions.Count
        Debug.Print "Revision " & i & " Author: " & ActiveDocument.Revisions(i).Author 'works
        Debug.Print "Revision " & i & " Creator: " & ActiveDocument.Revisions(i).Creator 'works
        Debug.Print "Revision " & i & " Date: " & ActiveDocument.Revisions(i).Date 'works
        Debug.Print "Revision " & i & " FormatDescription: " & ActiveDocument.Revisions(i).FormatDescription 'works...
        Debug.Print "Revision " & i & " Range: " & ActiveDocument.Revisions(i).Range 'work
        Debug.Print "Revision " & i & " Style: " & ActiveDocument.Revisions(i).Style 'error 5852
        Debug.Print "Revision " & i & " Type: " & ActiveDocument.Revisions(i).Type 'works
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs?

Comment: Please provide more context - code that you've tried so that we can repro.

Comment: And what is it, more exactly, you're trying to do? Change the color of the underlying text? Or the way the revision is displayed?

Comment: I added some more information.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, it's not possible to set the color for revisions per author, explicitly. It simply is *not* possible.

I believe that `Revisions.Style` is *not* for changing how a revision looks (color or anything else). I believe it's meant to return `Style` information, such as the name of the style and the various properties (analog to `Range.Style`). The error is because Word hasn't recorded such information, probably because it doesn't recognize the related style types...

There are two related(?) `Revision.Type` enums: `wdRevisionStyle`  and `wdRevisionStyleDefinition`. In a quick test - formatting using a style, creating a style and changing a style definition - I was not able to return either of these revision types. But according to the Language Reference they mean:

> wdRevisionStyle            8 Style changed.
>   wdRevisionStyleDefinition 13 Style definition changed.

In my tests, the type of revision returned for applying a style is `wdRevisionParagraphProperty` and changing a style definition is not recorded as a Revision.

For `Revision.Style` to return information I believe you'd need to test whether the `Revision.Type` is either of the above and only then would there be a valid object in `Revision.Style`.

I'm looking at Word 2010.